# "Positively homogeneous of degree zero"

Tags: functions

I am trying to understand a statement in an economics paper (and this paper is unfortunately quite sloppily written).

Let $A$ be a finite set. Let $S$ be the set of real-valued functions on $A$, i.e. $ S = \{u:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\} $. Let $\lambda:S^{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{N}$. It is then stated that:

"$\lambda_{n} (\vec{u})$ *is positively homogeneous of degree zero in* $u_k,\forall k\neq n$"

My question is: How is the above statement to be interpreted? Right now, my interpretation is this:

"Let $t>0$. If for all $k \neq n$, $v_k(a)=tu_k(a),\forall a\in A$, then $\lambda_n (v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n-1},u_n,v_{n+1},\dots,v_N)=\lambda_n (u_1,u_2,\dots,u_{n-1},u_n,u_{n+1},\dots,u_N)$."

Is my interpretation correct?

**Addendum.** The paper can be found [here on JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41106277). The quoted statement is near the top of p. 525.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your interpretation is about 95% correct. Since the codomain of $\lambda$ is $\mathbb R^N$, I think that $\lambda_n$ refers to the $n$-th component of $\lambda$. For instance, if $n = 3$, we could write

$$
\lambda(u_1, u_2, u_3) = (\lambda_1(u_1, u_2, u_3), \lambda_2(u_1, u_2, u_3), \lambda_3(u_1, u_2, u_3)),
$$

and the assertion about homogeneity more or less says that $\lambda_i$ depends only on $u_i$, at least up to positive scalar multiples of the other variables. An instance where this makes some sense is when $\lambda_1$ is my valuation of something, and the other $\lambda_i$s are other people's valuations. Perhaps my own sense of the item's value depends only on the other people's *ranking* of the items (which is best, 2nd best, etc.) and not on the specific numerical values that they assign to each.

The distinction between my version and yours is this: you have interpreted it to mean that, for instance, that
$$
\lambda_1(u_1, tu_2, tu_3) = \lambda_1(u_1, u_2, u_3),
$$
whereas I think it means that 
$$
\lambda_1(u_1, tu_2, u_3) = \lambda_1(u_1, u_2, u_3) \\
\lambda_1(u_1,  u_2, tu_3) = \lambda_1(u_1, u_2, u_3)
$$
i.e., that's it's homogeneous in the other variables *individually* rather than collectively.